# multi-line insert after indentation whitespace

Tags: indentation, multiple-lines

if I have a list of indented text

```
test test
    test test
    test test
test test
     test test
          test test
     test test
```

and I wanted to convert it to a markdown list

```
- test test
    - test test
    - test test
- test test
     - test test
          - test test
     - test test
```

what would be the best way to do this if vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. The way *I* would probably do it is this:

```
:%norm I-<space>
```

Note that the `<space>` should be a literal space, not the text `<space>`. This simply applies the set of keystrokes `I-<space>` to every line in the buffer. Uppercase `I` enters insert mode on the first non-whitespace character of the current line.

Of course, if you don't want it on *every* line, and instead on a few lines, you could visually select the lines and do

```
:norm I-<space>
```

This is the most straightforward approach. The other thing you could do is a substitute command. For example:

```
:%s/^ */&- /
```

Just as with the last command, if you visually select the lines you would like to do this to, you can run

```
:s/^ */&- /
```

instead to only do this to certain lines.

Comment: (`\s*` can be used instead of `­ *` in the `:s`ubstitute commands ­ for this to work with tabs as well as spaces indentation whitespace.)

Comment: Or, for the substitute, target non-whitespace with `:%s/\S/- &/`